# How to color row in mvc table if past 5 months since the date that in the table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am new with web development and  MVC, I have a Driver model, with `public LastEyeCheck { get; set; }` property, and in `index.cshtml` there is a table of drivers.

My question: I want to color in red the row with driver that past 5 months since his last eye check, how can I do that? where should I add the rquired code? in the `index.cshtml`? in the `model`? in the `controller`?

[image]

Driver model:

```
    public class Driver
    {
       [Key]

        public int LicenceID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        ....

        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime LastEyeCheck { get; set; }

        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    public class DriverDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
    }
```

index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<try4.Models.Driver>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/MyJs.js"></script>
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
       ....
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastEyeCheck)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        ....
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastEyeCheck)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.LicenceID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.LicenceID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.LicenceID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Again (as per your last question), use a view model have a calculated property that returns the number of months. Then you can conditional add a class attribute for the row.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can you post an answer and show me how please? I know how to program in c#, but I need to get use to mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to check if the date of the `LastEyeCheck` is overdue, which you can use by comparing it with today's date plus 5 months, for example

```
bool isOverDue = item.LastEyeCheck > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(5);
```

and then you can conditionally add a `class` or `style` attribute to the `<td>` element.

As for where the logic goes, it can go in the view or the model or the controller.

For example in the view only

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    bool isOverDue = item.LastEyeCheck > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(5);
    var className = isOverDue ? "class=overdue" : "";
    <tr @className>
        ....
```

or by creating a read-only property in a view model that return a `bool`

```
public class DriverVM
{
    ....
    public DateTime LastEyeCheck { get; set; }
    public bool IsOverDue
    {
        get { return LastEyeCheck > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(5); }
    }
}
```

and in the view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var className = item.isOverDue ? "class=overdue" : "";
    <tr @className>
        ....
```

or in the controller (with a simple `get; set;` property in your view model)

```
public class DriverVM
{
    ....
    public DateTime LastEyeCheck { get; set; }
    public bool IsOverDue { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<DriverVM> model = db.Drivers.ToList().Select(x => new DriverVM
    {
        ....
        LastEyeCheck = x.LastEyeCheck,
        IsOverDue = x.LastEyeCheck > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(5)
    });
    return View(model);
}
```

All these options will work, however its generally accepted in MVC that

- views should not contain complex logic (although this is view
  specific logic so its not unreasonable),
- views should be based on [view
  models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)
  and view models should be 'dumb' (simple `get; set;` properties),

and you need to consider what happens if you change your logic later based on other data (e.g. 5 months for Drivers aged over 60, but 12 months for those under), so my recommendation is to use the last option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@if` clause. Try something like this:

```
@if(item.LastEyeCheck > 5){ //here you have to do some date comparison
   <td style="background-color: red"> //td -> red
       Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastEyeCheck)
   </td>
}else{ 
   <td>
       Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastEyeCheck)
   </td>
}
```